# From Excel to Quant mod

Tags: excel, quantmod

I am doing some simple analysis using `quantmod`, my file is in `Excel csv` file.

The first column is the date format `YYYY-MM-DD`, I then have ten columns containing price data, each represents a fund or index.  None of the data is on yahoo, so I cannot use `getSymbols`.

Could someone give the code to bring the excel file into `R` in a format workable with `Quantmod` in an understandable form that a non-programmer can understand?

Comment: It looks like this has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970823/how-to-load-csv-data-file-into-r-for-use-with-quantmod)

Comment: Hi Papa Kojo - I had read that, but it made little sense to me. It would be great if someone could write down the code to bring in Excel csv in a mode that Quant mod can use.  I can import the csv file and it reads ok - then it all goes pear shaped.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you have is that if you read the CSV file into R it is a dataframe object. Use the class() function to confirm.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(quantmod)
library(timekt)

my_data <- readr::read_csv('my excel file.csv')
class(my_data)
```

To use quantmod function your data needs to be in an xts object (time-series object), it can't be in a dataframe. You can convert a dataframe that has a date/index column into an xts object using the timekt::tk_xts() function. And then you should be able to use quantmod functions for analysis on your data.

```
my_xts <- timekt::tk_xts(my_data)
quantmod::monthlyReturns(my_xts)
```